# Invariants of a subgroup.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I've been struggling many hours trying to solve this problem from the book: Topics in Algebra, of Herstein (2nd edition). If anybody can give me a hint for the solution, I would really appreciate that.

If $G$ is an abelian group of order $p^n$ with invariants $n_1\geq \cdots\geq n_k>0$ and $H\neq (e)$ is a subgroup of $G$, show that if $h_1\geq\cdots\geq h_s>0$ are the invariants of $H$, then $k\geq s$ and for each $i$, $h_i\leq n_i$.

Comment: I think, $h_i\leq n_i$?

Comment: Thanks, I've already changed that.

Comment: As in the book, define $G(r) = \{ x \in G: x^r = 1\}$. To prove the first inequality $k \geq s$, you can use the corollary of lemma 2.14.2, which states that $|G(p)| = p^k$.

Comment: Thanks.. that is the easy part of the problem, are the other inequalities that don't let me sleep, but thank you for  your try.

Answer (score 3):

The subgroups that m.k. denoted by $G(r)$ are often called the Omega subgroups and, in a $p$-group $G$, $G(p^i)$ is denoted by $\Omega_i(p)$.

The `Agemo' subgroups are defined as $\mho^i(G) := \langle  g^{p^i} \mid g \in G \rangle$.

The invariants of $G$ are $n_1 \ge n_2 \ge n_k > 0$, where $k=d(G)$ is the minimal number of generators of $G$. Then $d(\mho^i(G))$ is equal to the number of $n_j$ with $n_j > i$.

For a subgroup $H$ of $G$, $\mho^i(H) \le \mho^i(G)$, and so $d(\mho^i(H)) \le  d(\mho^i(G))$. You can use that to deduce that $h_i \le n_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: How the last inequality $h_i\leq n_i$ follows from the penultimate inequality?

Comment: How the last inequality $h_i\leq n_i$ follows from the penultimate inequality?

Comment: That is straightforward, and it would be tedious to write down a formal proof. For example, if $h_1 > n_1$ then we would have $d(\mho^{n_1}(H)) > d(\mho^{n_1}(G))=0$.

Comment: Thanks, dear Derek! I got your hint.